# Why sometimes android studio doesn't print stacktrace in logcat

Tags: android

I use `Retrofit 2.8.1` to make a network call. When I disable my network connection, the app crashes. But strangely I've got nothing about stack trace on logcat. Just says:

```
E/AndroidRunTime: FATAL EXEPTION: main
Process: ir.kaaveh.recyclerviewmvvm, PID: 31179
```

When I surround my network call with `try/catch` and use `e.printStackTrace()`, I find out that:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.omdbapi.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Why Android studio don't show me stack trace in this case? Usually, it tells you which line causes throw exception.
You can find the full source code [here](https://github.com/Kaaveh/RecyclerView_with_MVVM/tree/2101e159e173d9f0acb8302b6e34e775951eb4f8).

Comment: It's not Android studio that prints the stack trace but your program. When you caught the exception, what did you put into the catch clause?

Comment: Check the filters in the logcat, set it to "No fliters" and you should see it there.

Comment: When the app crashes, it means something has happened that is out of your `try-catch` control. In other words, when you expect `e.printStackTrace()` to print a log, it means your app has not yet crashed. So the reason is something different that what you expect.

Comment: It didn't crash in API 21+. But on an emulator with API level 19, it did, simply because retrofit needed API level 21+.

Comment: @Vucko No, It does not make any difference.

Comment: @Henry I simply lunch a coroutine that makes a network call without check connectivity. please see [here](https://github.com/Kaaveh/RecyclerView_with_MVVM/blob/2101e159e173d9f0acb8302b6e34e775951eb4f8/app/src/main/java/ir/kaaveh/recyclerviewmvvm/repository/MovieRepository.kt#L13)

Comment: @Sajjad I tested it on API 23 and crashed. My problem is why it doesn't print stack trace.